# Volley Request status is false and response is null in Android when press the Back button

Tags: android, android-volley

I am getting the false status while hitting the api by using the Volley library. I tried to debug the code many times but I did not understand  where I'm doing wrong; seems like I am passing the params and everything fine.

I got the below error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'byte[] com.android.volley.NetworkResponse.data' on a null object reference
                                              at com.pcnc.bop.helpers.VolleyRequest$2.onErrorResponse(VolleyRequest.java:98)
                                              at com.android.volley.Request.deliverError(Request.java:577)
                                              at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:101)
                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Comment: Are you able to get data on browser @Shine

Comment: actually we could not able to get it from browser due to some secure reasons.but am getting the response from first time running the app. when I click back button from third fragment to first fragment that time it is giving false response.

Comment: post some related code how your making your url?